# Query to extract ids from a deeply nested json array object in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I'm using Presto and trying to extract all 'id' from 'source'='dd' from a nested json structure as following.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "docs": [
        {
          "id": "apple1",
          "source": "dd"
        },
        {
          "id": "apple2",
          "source": "aa"
        },
        {
          "id": "apple3",
          "source": "dd"
        }
      ],
      "group": 99806
    }
  ]
}
```

expected to extract the ids [apple1, apple3] into a column in Presto
I am wondering what is the right way to achieve this in Presto Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data has a regular structure as in the example you posted, you can use a combination of [parsing the value as JSON](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse), casting it to a structured SQL type (array/map/row) and the using [array processing functions](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) to [filter](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#filter), [transform](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#transform) and extract the elements you want:

```sql
WITH data(value) AS (VALUES '{
  "results": [
    {
      "docs": [
        {
          "id": "apple1",
          "source": "dd"
        },
        {
          "id": "apple2",
          "source": "aa"
        },
        {
          "id": "apple3",
          "source": "dd"
        }
      ],
      "group": 99806
    }
  ]
}'),
parsed(value) AS (
  SELECT cast(json_parse(value) AS row(results array(row(docs array(row(id varchar, source varchar)), "group" bigint))))
  FROM data
)
SELECT 
  transform(                                        -- extract the id from the resulting docs
    filter(                                         -- filter docs with source = 'dd'
        flatten(                                    -- flatten all docs arrays into a single doc array
             transform(value.results, r -> r.docs)  -- extract the docs arrays from the result array
        ),
        doc -> doc.source = 'dd'),
    doc -> doc.id)
FROM parsed
```

The query above produces:

```
      _col0
------------------
 [apple1, apple3]
(1 row)
```